# Coq IDE icon missing from favorites

Tags: coq, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Coq and Coq IDE from [here](https://coq.inria.fr/opam-using.html). Everything went smooth.
I launched the Coq IDE from terminal, then I right clicked it to add it to my favorites and that was not possible. When I looked for its icon in my programs it wasn't there. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, can it be done?

Comment: Do you need an compiled version of coq ide or only coq ide working on your machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `coqide.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` by imitating the ones present in `/usr/share/applications`.

The difficulty is that the `opam` installation may include multiple switches, each with one version of Coq. Thus it is not clear what binary must be pointed to by the shortlink you want to create.

I see two solutions:

- choosing the version of Coq present in the current global opam switch. That's what I used for a few months a year ago. If the current opam switch does not contain a Coq binary, launching CoqIDE from the shortlink silently fails. I think I used a command similar to `zsh -ic coqide` (because `zsh` is my main shell, you may adapt this command to your own shell). I call `zsh` so that it loads the opam environment and can find the right `coqide`. The `-i` may not be necessary, but I remembered that without it, `zsh` was not loading the opam environment in my case.
- choosing the version of Coq present in a given switch. You just have to adapt the previous point so that the right switch is selected before calling `coqide`. This gives

  ```
  zsh -ic "eval $(opam env --switch myswitch) coqide"
  ```

I am not sure that running an executable by calling the shell is a good practice (I would say it is not), but at least it works and I do not see how to load the opam environment without such a hack.

Comment: Actually, in the second case, you could also avoid calling `opam` since you know the paths statically.